# Viewstate persistence

Tags: asp.net, controls, viewstate

Lets say I have a page, which has one usercontrol (A) on it. This user control has many other server and user controls as its children. If I disable the viewstate on usercontrol A, do all the children inside lose their viewstate also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child  controls will also lose their viewstate.  See this previous question for more details: [How do I enable ViewState for child custom controls when disabled in parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175252/how-do-i-enable-viewstate-for-child-custom-controls-when-disabled-in-parent)

Comment: Thanks. Just want to double check.